# Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am running the following Facebook FQL for my iOS app. It is giving me the error:

I have tested the permissions and they seem to be fine. Also the bundle id in the facebook app (on the developers section) matches the bundle id on the app. How do I fix this issue ?

## Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

```
-(void)FetchFBFriends
{
```

`// Query to fetch the active user's friends, limit to 25.
NSString *query =
@"SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE is_app_user=0 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ";
// Set up the query parameter
NSDictionary *queryParam =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];

// Make the API request that uses FQL
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                              FBFriendsArray = (NSArray *) [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                              //NSLog(@"FBFriendsArray %@",FBFriendsArray);
                              [FBFriendListTableView reloadData];

                          }
                      }];`

}